# Script to run an exe with parameters and catch exit code

Tags: powershell

I have an import tool that has support for running in unattended mode. It accepts arguments like this:

importer.exe -organization "DEV" -dataFile "E:\importData.txt" -rightsFile "E:\importRights.txt" -logFile "C:\LogFile.log"

Now above is how the tool itself accepts the arguments.

I'm writing a ps-script to launch the tool with the above parameters.

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Executes the PWR Bulk Data Importer tool in unattended mode.

    .DESCRIPTION
    This script executes the PWR Bulk Data Importer tool in unattended mode. The Import files: Data and rights must be supplied and log file must also be provided.

    .PARAMETER ImportToolExe
    The full path and exe of the tool.

    .PARAMETER Organization
    The identifier of the organization.

    .PARAMETER DataFile
    The full path and filename of data file.

    .PARAMETER RightsFile
    The full path and filename of rights file.

    .PARAMETER LogFile
    The full path and filename of log file (will be created and if already exists, it'll be over-writtien).

    .PARAMETER IsForced
    If true, tool will run in override mode omitting all deletion warnings.

    .EXAMPLE
    Executer -ImportToolExe "D:\tool\PWR Bulk Data Importer.exe" -Organization "VTDEV" -DataFile "E:\importData.txt" -RightsFile "E:\importRights.txt" -LogFile "C:\LogFile.log"
    Executer -ImportToolExe "D:\tool\PWR Bulk Data Importer.exe" -Organization "VTDEV" -DataFile "E:\importData.txt" -RightsFile "E:\importRights.txt" -LogFile "C:\LogFile.log" -IsForced true
#>

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$ImportToolExe,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$Organization,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$DataFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 3, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$RightsFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 4, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$LogFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [bool]$IsForced
)

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "Script to execute Bulk Data Importer"
Write-Output ""

$params = "-organization " + $Organization + " -dataFile " + $DataFile + " -rightsFile " + $RightsFile + " -logFile " + $LogFile

Write-Output "Debuging"
Write-Output ($ImportToolExe + " " + $params)

Try
{
    Write-Output " "
    Write-Output "Executing..."
    Invoke-Expression ($ImportToolExe + " " + $params)

    Write-Output "Finished."
    Write-Output "Checking exit code."    

}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    " "
    "Exception while trying to execute"
    Write-Output $_.Exception.GetType().FullName; 
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message;
    return
}
Finally
{
    Write-Output " "
}

$IsImportSuccess = $false

IF ($lastexitcode -eq 0)
{
    Write-Output "Import successful."
    $IsImportSuccess = $true
}
ELSE
{
    Write-Output "Import failed."
    $IsImportSuccess = $false
}

IF ($IsImportSuccess -eq $true)
{
    Try
    {
        $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
        $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SMTPClient( $SmtpServer, 587 )  
        $SMTPClient.EnableSSL = $true 
        $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( "GMAIL_USERNAME", "GMAIL_PASSWORD" ); 


        $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $emailMessage.From = $EmailFrom
        foreach ( $recipient in $Arry_EmailTo )
        {
            $emailMessage.To.Add( $recipient )
        }
        $emailMessage.Subject = $EmailSubj
        $emailMessage.Body = $EmailBody

        # Do we have any attachments?
        # If yes, then add them, if not, do nothing
        # if ( $Arry_EmailAttachments.Count -ne $NULL ) 
        # {
        #   $emailMessage.Attachments.Add()
        # }

        $emailMessage.Attachments.Add($LogFile)

        $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
    }
    Catch [system.exception]
    {
        " "
        "Exception while emailing"
        write-host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName; 
        write-host $_.Exception.Message;
        return
    }
}
```

No I'm getting output with errors:

```
Script to execute Bulk Data Importer

Debuging
D:\tool\PWR Bulk Data Importer.exe -organization VTDEV -dataFile E:\importData.txt -rightsFile E:\importRights.txt -logFile C:\LogFile.log

Executing...

Exception while trying to execute
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
The term 'D:\tool\PWR' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I'm facing a bit of learning curve with PS and had this script up by reading from SO so far.

I see the main issue where I print a debug line: All my quotes are gone already. And my manager told me that the Invoke-Expression is not a good idea. He recommends me to use Start-something

Now I'm stuck. Any pointer will be greatly appreciated and there will be upvotes as well.

Comment: It is better practice to use _try/catch_ statements rather than rely on exit code. Here is a tutorial, it will make your code more readable too: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx

Comment: The exe is not throwing exceptions. I have made it too. There are 5 exit codes. So thats pretty much controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` inside try/catch, this should trigger desired action:

```
try{
    ...
    Invoke-Expression ($ImportToolExe + " " + $params) -ErrorAction Stop
    ...
}
catch{
    ## catch code
}
```

You can also try `Invoke-Command` to start the exe so in your scenario replace `Invoke-Expression` with the following:

```
Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {&$ImportToolExe $args[0]} -ArgumentList $params
```